# how does spring-boot understand not to create a bean more than one in this example?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, spring-bean

Please consider:

**Project A**

```
com.mycompany
 - SpringBootApp.java

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(MyConf.class)
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Project B**

```
com.mycompany.projectB
- MyConf.java
com.mycompany.projectB.beans
- Bean1.java
- Bean2.java
```

where `Bean1.java` and `Bean2.java` are `@Component` annotated classes.
and `Context.java` has content:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyConf {

}
```

Now Bean1 and Bean2 are eligible to be part of the application context because of the following reasons:

1. `SpringBootApp.java` is defined at an higher path hierarchy level
2. `MyConf.java` is defined at an higher path hierarchy level and will be 
    automatically imported in ProjectA because of point 1
3. I’m explicitely importing the context of project B from projectA  `@Import(MyConf.class)`

**My Question is:**
How does spring boot understand that what I really want is just one instance of the class
and how does it avoid to throw an exception like duplicate bean definition ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: ``Context.java`` can not have ``public class MyConf`` (compile error)

Comment: I don't see reasons for "duplicate bean definition exception" in your code. Two beans are instances of different classes, why should they collide?

Comment: Question seems vague: what is "the class" in this instance?
Do you want a single ApplicationContext? Do you want two different ApplicationContext instances, sharing the same beans?